# is it safe to use a text file that is modified by c++ and is not closed?

Tags: c++, unix, file-io

The title is not so clear but what I mean is this:

```
std::fstream filestream("abc.dat", std::ios::out);
double write_to_file;

while (some_condition) {

    write_to_file = 1.345; ///this number will be different in each loop iteration
    filestream.seekg( 345 );
    filestream << std::setw(5) << write_to_file << std::flush;
    ///write the number to replace the number that is written in the previous iteration

    system( "./Some_app ./abc.dat" ); ///open an application in unix, 
    ////which uses "abc.dat" as the input file
}
filestream.close();
```

that's the rough idea, each iteration re-write the number into the file and flush. I'm hoping not to open and close the file in each iteration, in order to save computing time. (also not sure of the complexity of open and close :/ ) Is it ok to do this?

Comment: ./Some_app is in fact also a c++ program which reads but not change the file

Answer (score 1):

On unix, `std::flush` does not necessarily write to the physical device. Typically, it does not. `std::ofstream::flush` calls `rdbuf->pubsync()`, which in turn calls `rdbuf->sync()`, which in turn "synchronizes the controlled sequences with the arrays." What are those "control sequences"? Typically they're not the underlying physical device. In a modern OS such as unix, there are lots of things in between high level I/O constructs such as C++'s concept of an I/O buffer and the bits on the device.

Even the low-level POSIX function `fsync()` does not necessarily guarantee that bits are written to the device. Even closing and reopening the output file does not necessarily guarantee that bits are written to the device.

You might want to rethink your design.

Comment: Of course, it probably doesn't matter if the bits are written to the device, so long as the child process is reading from the same block cache the parent process flushed to.

Comment: in the official website cplusplus.com it never says that flush will update the file :(

Comment: But cplusplus.com says when doing std::stream::close() "Any pending output sequence is written to the file"

Answer (score 0):

You need at least to flush the C++ stream buffer with `filestream.flush()` before calling `system` (but you did that with `<< std::flush;`)

I am assuming that `./Someapp` is not writing the file, and is opening it for reading only.

But in your case, better open and close the file at each iteration, since the `system` call is obviously a huge bottleneck.